# Autocomplete Apps Script, Google Advanced Services in VS Code

Tags: google-apps-script, visual-studio-code, google-admin-sdk, clasp

I've just started working on GAS projects with `clasp` and VS Code. Auto-complete works well for most every built-in library that works in the web-based script editor. However the Advanced Services, like AdminDirectory seem not to be included in the `@types/google-apps-script` package from npm. See the screenshot.

[image: AdminDirectory not found]

Is there any other package or workaround that will allow the Advanced Services to auto-complete in VS Code?

Comment: It's in the works. Alternative is to create your own types file

Comment: Good news. Where is the best place to stay notified on that development?

Comment: Fork DefintelyTyped and create PR, If you want it done now. Instructions [here](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now included in the `@types/google-apps-script` package:

```
Global values: AdminDirectory, ...
```